# Is it possible to attach a message to a git commit that will display when pulled?

Tags: git, github

I work in a large codebase with >100 developers pushing/merging to the same branch often, and occasionally people push up changes that require extra steps after pulled. In an ideal world, communication is a good solution, but in practice we all know that's not going to work 100% of the time.

I'm looking for a git or github feature that allows us to either flag a commit or merge as needing extra steps, or somehow including a message that will be displayed when that commit is pulled.

Commit messages are great, but it's not feasible to require every developer manually `git log` after every pull to see if they need to do something.

For example, it would be great if I could add a message like "requires `npm install` after pull" to a commit in which I modify `package.json`, and when pulled the message is displayed.

**EDIT (5/21/18)**

See accepted answer for what I ended up doing. The `post-merge` hook solved the functionality I was looking for, and does not rely on the developer "marking" or "leaving a message" on their commit.

Comment: You could use the `post-merge` and `post-checkout` hooks to inspect the history -- though at scale you probably want to get developers in the habit of updating installed dependencies *every* time they pull (and email out to a shared mailing list when larger breaking changes occur).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `post-merge` hook as suggested in a comment to my original question.

```
PACKAGE_JSON_CHANGED=$(git diff --name-only HEAD@{1} HEAD | grep --color=never -E "^package\.json$")
if [ "${PACKAGE_JSON_CHANGED}" != "" ]; then
    echo -e "package.json was modified, you might need to run 'npm install'!"
fi
```

It is correct that this has nothing to do with "attaching" anything to the commit as my question was asking for, but rather using `post-merge` since all pulls inherently merge. I could, if I desired, call `npm install` directly within the hook, but chose to echo to allow the developer to run it at their discretion.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "no".  The long answer starts with "yes", but continues with "sort of, only it's going to end badly..."

You could try to rig something up with hooks, but those hooks would have to be configured by each developer; and it's still not clear how this would work.  Keep in mind that the commit requiring special handling might never be explicitly pulled or fetched by some developers; so you'd have to do something like identify all of the "newly fetched" commits and display messages corresponding to any/all of them.

Similarly, if it *really* were just a matter of being impractical to require developers to run `git log`, you could standardize on everyone using an alias that did a `fetch` (or `pull`) and then showed the `log`.  But again, the real issue is whether developers should be expected to read the log messages for *every new commit they just fetched*.  (They should not.)

There are other ways to attach information to a commit - such as annotated tags, or notes - so that they would stand out from the sea of existing commit log data.  But now you're requiring extra steps when creating "special" commits, and you still have to figure out how to get all developers reading the messages after every `fetch`.

A better solution is to deliver the "extra steps" in scripted form as part of the commit.  The standard way to do that is through your build tooling.  Since I don't know your build tooling, I can't offer details; but the type of step you describe (`npm install`) should run as part of every build anyway, as these commands already "know" only to do what's necessary in light of changes.

Comment: Yes, this is a build / deploy problem, not a VC problem.